# ExpressJS - Blocked by client - Unable to load js file?

Tags: javascript, html, express, heroku

I have loaded my express app on a server (I used heroku). When I test my app locally it works fine but when I load the page on the web it gives me a **net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT** saying that it is not able to load a JS file that I define in the HTML page:

```
<script src="./index.js"></script>
```

If I try to go to: `http://<my-page>/index.js` it is able to load the file successfully.
Why this doesn't work?

(If you need more information tell me what I need to add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. There was a problem with the Avira Chrome extension that was blocking the file from loading. I simply added my page to the whitelist and it started working as supposed.